# How to change ngDialog size at runtime

Tags: css, ng-dialog

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically change a size of ngDialog that I use for my popups. The dialog fires event when it's been opened:

```
 $scope.$on('ngDialog.opened', function (e, $dialog) {
    dialogReady($dialog);
});
```

I tried all of these:

```
  function dialogReady(caseEditorWindow) {
    caseEditorWindow.css({ 'width' : '1350px' });
    caseEditorWindow.width(1350);
    caseEditorWindow.css('width', '1350px' });
}
```

Nothing takes any effect.

It only gets sized if I use a class like this:

```
<style>
.ngdialog.dialogcaseeditor .ngdialog-content
    {
        width : 1350px;
        height: 810px;
        margin-top:-100px;
        padding-top:10px;
    }
 </style>
```

at the time of creating the dialog:

```
ngDialog.open({
        template: 'caseEditor.html', 
        controller: 'caseEditorController',
        className: 'ngdialog-theme-default dialogcaseeditor',
        closeByDocument: false,
        disableAnimation: true,
        scope: $scope
        data: row 
    })
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`var dialog = ngDialog.open();`  //always return object {id: 'div attr id'};

`$('#'+ dialog.id).css('width', '100px');`  //You can get outer div like this

Althrough, not so good using jquery in angular controller, but it works (the only way).